# How to use GeoLite City, how to obtain startIpNum and endIpNum

Tags: geoip, maxmind, geolitecity

Alright i downloaded from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/ `GeoLite City` database.

The values are in the `GeoLiteCity-Blocks.csv`

```
startIpNum,endIpNum,locId
"16777216","16777471","17"
```

However i have no idea how to convert ips to these startIpNum and endIpNum range. I cant find on their site and they link to here

What is the algorithm to convert ip v4 into this ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends which programmation language you use.

In php, you can use ip2long and long2ip to work with ips.

```
string long2ip ( string $proper_address )
The function long2ip() generates an Internet address in dotted format (i.e.: aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd) from the proper address representation.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php

Example with the ips you give: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3decd3d4818a02d65b9a80cf2dc1c70297b0d2d5

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Python, you could use

```
>>> import socket, struct
>>> socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', 16777216))
'1.0.0.0'
```

to convert from integer to IP string.